# Type inference: Generics, "var"

Tags: java, generics, type-inference, java-10

I thought the Java compiler (Java 11) could infer by itself the actual generic type, if I gave it enough hints, for example when the generic type is a method parameter and I provide as a parameter an instance of the actual type.

For example, I have the following class:

```
public class Var<T>
{
    public T value;

    public Var(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Then, I try the following 3 attempts, which I expected all to compile:

```
//(1) Compilation error!
Var v = new Var(0);
++v.value;

//(2) Compilation error!
Var v = new Var<Integer>(0);
++v.value;

//(3) Compiles!
Var<Integer> v = new Var(0);
++v.value;
```

1) I would expect (1) to compile, because by using an `Integer` (or `int`) parameter, it may be enough for the compiler to know the actual type. So in `++v.value;` I would expect the compiler to know that the variable is an `Integer`, but it does not. It still thinks it is an `Object`.

2) Adds some explicit information. But still the compiler does not understand.

3) Compiles, as expected.

Then, I try type inference with the `var` keyword:

```
//(4) Compilation error!
var v = new Var(0);
++v.value;

//(5) Compiles!
var v = new Var<Integer>(0);
++v.value;
```

4) Again, I would expect (4) to compile, since the type can be inferred from the parameter.

5) (After correcting my syntax:) Compiles, as expected.

**Questions:**

Could you explain why this code fails in the cases (1), (2), (4)?

Is there a way to make the `var` keyword type inference work with such a class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I would expect (1) to compile,

This is a raw type and is similar to writing

```
Var<Object> v = new Var<Object>();
```

but Object doesn't support `++`

This is implied based on the `class Var<T>` which is shorthand for `class Var<T extends Object>` so if you have a raw type, it assumes the type `T` extends.

> Adds some explicit information. But still the compiler does not understand.

The code doesn't compile I suggest adding the information in the right place.

```
Var<Integer> v = new Var<>();
```

or

```
Var<Integer> v = new Var<Integer>();
```

> Is there a way to make the var keyword type inference work with such a class

The `var` is just a shorthand, and if the code wouldn't work without it, adding it won't help.

Comment: I did not understand your "raw type" point. Here is a raw type: `List list = new ArrayList();`. It does not provide any information on the actual type. But `new Var(0)` does provide some information on what the actual parameter type is. I thought I did see examples in the past where in a generic method, the complier figured out by itself the actual generic type, if it was a method parameter, so it was not required to explicitly specify it by <Type>.

Comment: @rapt For constructors, no type inference for the class is taken from the arguments, raw or otherwise. If you use a generic class, it is validated, but no inference occurs.

Comment: I thought type validation and type inference are tightly related when dealing with generic classes? First the actual generic type is identified - either inferred or specified explicitly - and then all uses of the generic instance are validated. If I have instead the following generic method `<U> Var var(U value) { return new Var<>(value); }` - How could I make `var v = var(0); ++v.value;` compile?

Comment: You would need `<U> Var<U> var(U value)` but even then, I am not sure it will work as you expect.

Comment: You are right... without that syntax it was interpreted again as a raw type. With this change `++v.value;` does compile.

Answer (score 2):

The correct syntax would be:

```
var v = new Var<Integer>(0);
```

`new <Integer>Var(0)` is the obscure syntax for using a generic constructor (much the same as a generic method). You have a generic type.

The original code should be generating a ton of raw type warning messages.

Comment: My bad, you are right... although that specific line did compile with the `new <Integer>Var(0)` syntax, I wonder why. Anyway, I will correct my syntax in (2) & (5) in my question. But still my question stands - isn't `new Var(0)` supposed to hint the compiler that the type is `Integer`, for example I thought that would make (4) work?

Comment: `new Var(0)` would be a raw type. Do you mean `new Var<>(0)`?

Comment: Yes... but how do I specify such syntax when I call the generic constructor through a generic method? For example `<U> Var var(U value) { return new Var<>(value); }` and then I want to do something like `var v = var(0);`

Comment: There is no generic constructor here. Generic methods don't require the diamond syntax of constructors of generic classes. (Also of note, the usual terminology doesn't match the JLS.)

Comment: @rapt you simply have to stop your habit of using *raw types*. Since `Var` is generic, you have to provide a type argument instead of writing `Var`. So when you want to write a generic method, you have to write `<U> Var<U> var(U value) { return new Var<>(value); }` (note the `<U>` at the return type). Then, you can write `var v = var(0);` without any problems. Likewise, you can write `var v = new Var<>(0);` without any problems, the compiler will infer the correct type from the constructor argument. *When* you use `Var<>` instead of `Var`…